# Stored procedure using PYODBC Not loading destination table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pandas, stored-procedures, etl, pyodbc

```
def UploadTable(table):

    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXXXX;Database=XXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE dr.Imported_OM01TMP4_Data")

    create_statement = fts.fast_to_sql(table,  "dr.Imported_OM01TMP4_Data", conn, if_exists="append")

    cur.execute("EXEC [dr].[PopulateGlAccountRevenue_Files_UltimateEdition_DeltaLoad]")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Please see my code snippet above, I am trying to run this stored procedure `[dr].[PopulateGlAccountRevenue_Files_UltimateEdition_DeltaLoad]` that is already defined in SQL Server.

My code runs fine but when I check to see if the destination table in the server is loaded with the data from the table `dr.Imported_OM01TMP4_Data`, I am seeing a blank.

When I populate the same table with my python code but execute the stored procedure in SQL Server, the destination table is loaded properly. Is this a permissions / access issue? I have DB Owner Access/Read/Write as well, so I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Please advise.

Comment: So MSSQL can be blocked by a firewall on the server, or it could be you just are not connecting to the database at all (for many other reasons).  Have you verified that you can even see the database from your dev environment (not locally on the database server).  Like verifying you can connect with a test ODBC connection or something?

Comment: @Musselman I have verified that I am connected to the database and I can query the table ```dr.Imported_OM01TMP4_Data``` and I can query the destination table that the procedure should load to. So that is not the issue.

Comment: table is a reserved word in T-SQL.  I know that might not be the current issue, but it would be a good idea to not use that as a var name.

Comment: what is `fts.fast_to_sql` where is `fts` defined? also you should add in the proc to your question so we can reproduce.

Comment: @Manakin fts is a sql object that has the method ```fast_to_sql``` which is equivalent to .NET's ```BulkCopy``` functionality it also takes a pandas df in this case the ```table``` parameter whose schema matches the destination table parameter as denoted  by the string, and the sql connection to the specified server and db in my connection string.

Comment: @Manakin ```fast_to_sql``` is a library that gets imported to be clear. I have a feeling my sql connection/database isn't finding the stored procedure in MSSQL even though the stored procedure object exists within MSSQL on my dev environment.